# d3.js - fixed position for tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For a chord diagram I would like to add a tooltip windows in the upper right corner of the screen (for each element).

At the moment I use the following code for a tooltip wich is positioned next to the cursor:

```
       function mouseclick(d) {
           div.style("left", d3.event.pageX+15 + "px")
               .style("top", d3.event.pageY-30 + "px")
               .style("opacity", 1)
               .html(output);
       }
```

So far I was not able put the tooltip into a same position for elements.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle, so that we could work on it, and get it you..